# Any transformer model (NLP) for code classification?

Tags: classification, nlp, transformer, text-classification, code

Does any Transformer (NLP) that is suitable for code classification tasks exist?

For example, I have a lot of source codes of various categories (driver, game, email client, etc.). I want to distinguish (classify) these types using such a model.

Many thanks for considering my question.